# Should an Aggregate Root Implement an Interface in Domain-Driven Design

Tags: tdd, domain-driven-design

I'm working on a project using both domain-driven design and test-driven development.  While reading through the DDD book by Evans, I noticed that he did not define interfaces for aggregate roots in the domain.

If I'm doing both DDD and TDD, should I define interfaces for each aggregate root to make the aggregate root classes easily testable and mockable?  If so, should I also define interfaces for each entity contained within the aggregate root as well?

From my searches on Google and StackOverflow, I've found answers that come close to what I'm looking for, but I'm specifically look for advice when doing both DDD and TDD because my assumption is that testability, when doing TDD, might be overlooked in the answers that I've seen so far.

Comment: that's a broad question. you might want to give an example of what your building to get more specific answers. as it stands you might  get the 'it depends' answer a lot

Comment: Hubson, I apologize for the broadness of the question.  To clarify, I'm specifically trying to determine if Evans intentionally did not define interfaces for aggregate roots in his examples in the book to keep the examples simple (i.e. to disregard aspects, like TDD, outside of the topic of the book) or if he excluded them because they do not provide any additional value even when doing TDD.  The example in question would be the cargo application Evans used as his example in the book Domain-Driven Design.  I hope this helps narrow down the scope of the question. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: no apology needed, and that makes in concrete. just passing on what I've learned. people love this kind of question paired with "here's where i'm at" code / architecture diagrams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, test directly against the aggregate. The aggregate itself shouldn't have injected dependencies and if a specific behavior requires a dependency, that should usually be expressed as an interface. An interface on an aggregate is a needless abstraction - there is only one implementation of behaviors - that is the point. Also, take a look at [BDD and DDD](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/bdd-and-ddd) - Behavior-Driven Development can be seen as an evolution of TDD and aligns nicely with DDD.

Comment: can we talk about what you mean for needless abstraction? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28305/domain-driven-design

Comment: I've done quite a bit more research since I posted this question two days ago and what I've learned is that the question of creating interfaces for all domain entities (including aggregate roots) is a large and heavily debated topic (even without considering TDD or DDD). Given that, I assume that there is not going to be a clear cut answer. So I have to assume that Evans intentionally excluded interfaces for aggregate roots because of the reasons you've stated. Thus, I'm going to move forward with this approach and see how it goes. Thanks you for your feedback!

Answer (score 3):

I'm used to define [interfaces for all entities and domain services](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/poco.html) to ease the test of clients using the domain. Moreover such approach ease AOP when required.

As for value objects, it depends. For example I don't use interfaces for event arguments, [identifiers](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/shared_identifiers.html), [exceptions](http://epic.tesio.it/2013/03/04/exceptions-are-terms-ot-the-ubiquitous-language.html) (obviously) and some other kind of "contracts". However, I had to introduce interface to ease the isolation of client code testing. Thus my rule of thumbs is: how many step the client require to get the value object in the desired state? If it's more than one (or two, good sense is my friend :-D), I introduce an interface from the very begining.

**Note** I'm not talking about aggregates, since all my aggregates are entities too.